# Fitting a line through a complex 2D shape, use of multi-dimensional projection?

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis

I am working with a complex 2-dimensional shape (similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRtis.png)), and would like to pass a single, continuous line through it to aid future analyses. I have distinct data points on each pixel of this object and need to keep them independent and ordered.

After a while of trying to fit a line to it with different compromises/unfolding, I remembered that in linear regression, you map data points to higher dimensions, turning data that cannot be fitted by a line, into data that can be fitted by a line.

Is it possible to do a similar thing in this case? Would it be reasonable for me to try to map this object into 3-4+ dimensional space to get a line through it/ make it linear?

Does the fact that there are several "end points" mean that it would not be possible, at all, to linearize my object?

---

Edit (to add details):

I have data points on an object surface that looks like the above linked image. They are in a complex 2-dimensional shape, and analyzing them effectively is not practical while in this shape.

I want to transfer my data onto a line. On this line, I would like to keep the order of my data, and relationships between points.

I would like to do this while losing as little data as possible.

An example of what I was thinking of:

- Circle and 5 lines drawn in X,Y.
- Cut the circle at one point and unfold it (circle + 5lines would turn into line + 5 lines).
- Rotating my object in Z, and align my 5 lines to the 1 main line, as to have all lines in the same vertical plane as my object.
- Collapse my points.

This method is very inoptimal, and I would be:

1) losing a lot of data from it

2) disrupting some of the data on my main line (or circle).

Another example:

- "Blow up" my structure so as to have each line represented in two ways (center to edge, and edge back to center).
- Collapse the structure onto a line by disconnecting the circle at all line points
- What I would have is: Arc segment 1 > line1 up > line1 down > Arc segment 2 > line2 up > line2 down > Arc segment 3... etc

This method would make me lose the proximity relationship between the points on my arc.

I was wondering if mapping this structure onto higher dimensions before transforming it into a line would yield better results.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you have some measure of how well a line fits the shape?

Comment: I want to render my 2D object into a 1D line without losing the order of my data (or local relationships). Attempting a direct approach by unfolding the 2D object doesn't make it possible to turn it into a line (it solves the circle problem, but not the outward segments problem).

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are trying  to do. Do you mean a curve or a line?

Comment: Please add details... What you're asking is probably not a simple thing and has to be explained way better than this

Comment: I have added details to my original post. I think what I may be asking could be completely unreasonable / cannot be done.

Comment: @poultrynews: How about a graph-theoretic approach? Connect each data point in the same "pixel" with a zero-length edge, and each data point in neighboring "pixels" with an unit-length edge. Each path between any two data points (if connected) is then a wandering "line" through the object (so find and use the shortest one?). This preserves the locality only between neighboring pixels. Add edges to data points in second-, third-, etc. nearest neighbours (with edge lengths reflecting Euclidean distance), for wider "rigidity" in locality. (Apologies for the fuzzy terms in quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem, but if you have a sequence of 2-D points 
$$
(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \ldots, (x_n,y_n),
$$ 
then you can turn them into 3-D points like that:
$$
(x_1,y_1,h), (x_2,y_2,2h), \ldots, (x_n,y_n,nh),
$$
where $h$ is any non-zero quantity.
Could that help you?